# Trying to make sense of block headers from Infura

Tags: ethereum

I'm getting block headers as they come in from Infura, I'm printing the unix timestamp and then a few bits of data from the header. Can someone help me understand what is happening here, because it is quite confusing and not what I expected.

So for a long time I just got a header every 15 seconds. This changed after block 1735632... there was a 633, then 15 seconds later a different 633 along with a 634, then 14 seconds later, the original 633, a different 634 and a 635 - this is the chain that won out I guess, as 636 references the 635 block as parent.

So this situation is a fork and it's resolution. I'm just not totally clear on what happening. I would have though these alternate chains would have been broadcasted much nearer to each other time wise. Is Infura providing a sanitised view?

```
1575054262 - DATA {
  number: 1735632,
  hash: '0xfbc87f1b85453facc363d7aebea4a76ad179423dec808cf39afb100c574fda2e',
  parent: '0x8c6b92ce918094bccafbfa61d4b07f42767b84b9ff6d24dd22476e3c98f3a303'
}

1575054278 - DATA {
  number: 1735633,
  hash: '0x576ed76fbdf62c285ae60caf5f33ad2bc8d14b3eb3db33409bc2633ff9495c93',
  parent: '0xfbc87f1b85453facc363d7aebea4a76ad179423dec808cf39afb100c574fda2e'
}

1575054293 - DATA {
  number: 1735633,
  hash: '0x1f107e7911522d570003ab64d09ff8b69b3acb8b52ab1336b8df39117dbbf342',
  parent: '0xfbc87f1b85453facc363d7aebea4a76ad179423dec808cf39afb100c574fda2e'
}
1575054293 - DATA {
  number: 1735634,
  hash: '0x933b4c0f63bdf7e53219de0ffee48ccbfa6d858348219177f585d54fae6cd227',
  parent: '0x1f107e7911522d570003ab64d09ff8b69b3acb8b52ab1336b8df39117dbbf342'
}


1575054307 - DATA {
  number: 1735633,
  hash: '0x576ed76fbdf62c285ae60caf5f33ad2bc8d14b3eb3db33409bc2633ff9495c93',
  parent: '0xfbc87f1b85453facc363d7aebea4a76ad179423dec808cf39afb100c574fda2e'
}
1575054307 - DATA {
  number: 1735634,
  hash: '0x9bf027902d8b260f1bdf7fee10f05942c0dcab65128dd598ffb5e8f8c8a3e1f3',
  parent: '0x576ed76fbdf62c285ae60caf5f33ad2bc8d14b3eb3db33409bc2633ff9495c93'
}
1575054307 - DATA {
  number: 1735635,
  hash: '0xb4f11c2f1ef51cb0000e14aee0ff08abf4c5e760e2f193e3415871beee9484a9',
  parent: '0x9bf027902d8b260f1bdf7fee10f05942c0dcab65128dd598ffb5e8f8c8a3e1f3'
}



1575054322 - DATA {
  number: 1735636,
  hash: '0x090e0779338311318c77b4bad1e5f6701459c88ca285152e773f434db6615783',
  parent: '0xb4f11c2f1ef51cb0000e14aee0ff08abf4c5e760e2f193e3415871beee9484a9'
}
```